# What's the best way to inherit only a few properties from base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

What is the most capable way to inherit only a few properties from the base class. For example: I have a Figure class and Circle and Rectangle classes that inherit Figure. In a Figure class I have already implemented three properties width, height and radius. I can see that they are virtual, so I can override them. But is that the best way to do it? Is there any other way, e.g with interfaces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Without explaining in what sense you want those properties to be polymorphic, we have no way of judging whether you need it (virtual/override/interfaces/etc.) or not.  Please explain your *real* problem in far more detail.

Comment: _"In a Figure class I have already implemented three properties width, height and radius"_ - you went wrong at the start. Not all figures have a width, height or radius. A base class should be that: something that _all_ derived classes share. The _only_ property I can think of may be for example "color". Anyway this question might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com, but I'd suggest reading a bit more on the subject first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about object-oriented design.

Comment: @CodeCaster "you went wrong at the start. Not all figures have a width, height or radius.". That's the point - I didn't implement that three properties. It's by design

Comment: If this is not a hypothetical case and you have no control over the base class, then please explain so in your question and show the actual base class and the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @StanimirYakimov: No, the *point* is that it's a flawed design.  Whether or not they're implemented, every object exposes those properties.  If there's no shape that has all three of those properties, then there's no sensible object which can inherit from that base class.  The base class is broken.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem when you have to inherit only a few properties from a base class. It means that the class has too many jobs. You could stick with an interface Figure where you put all common methods for both Circle and Rectangle, and implement that in those classes. Also width and height belong only to Rectangle and radius belongs only to Circle

By doing what you just wrote you don't apply a well known principle: **Liskov substitution principle**  [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> If S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be
>   replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable
>   properties of that program

Answer (score 0):

With interfaces you can't inherit any behavior. It simply mandates that you  implement the behavior in the class that implements the interface. You can implement multiple interfaces, but it serves as a contract and not a base implementation. Base classes are more suitable in case where you have an actual implementation to share. You are limited to one base class in c# though.

Answer (score 0):

> In a Figure class I have already implemented three properties width, height and radius.

You've missed the point of inheritance then.  Defining these things in the base class means that *all* derived classes have *all* of these things.  What sort of shape has a width, a height, and a radius?

The base class should define only those things which are common across all derived classes.  It should *not* define everything which may potentially be on any given derived class.  This results in a single catch-all base class which tries to be everything, and simultaneously fails to accurately be anything.

Examples of properties which may be on a common polygon base class could be things like:

- Area
- Line weight
- Line color
- Fill color

Consider `Area` for a moment.  The abstract base class would define this property as abstract, because it doesn't know the dimensions by which a derived class would calculate the area.  All it knows is that, as a polygon, it will have an area.

Any given derived class would know internally how to calculate its area, and would implement that property as such.  A rectangle, for example, knows to use its width and height to make this calculation.  An abstract base polygon has no knowledge of width or height, so it just keeps an abstract placeholder for an area.

So any operation which only needs to know the area of a polygon, regardless of how that area is calculated, can be passed any object which inherits from this base polygon class.  It doesn't matter what the derived member is, any polygon would work.  If the operation, however, depended on something like a "width" then it would need a specific kind of derived object and not just any base polygon.

Inheritance is a relationship of "X *is a* Y" if X derives from Y.  That is, if `Rectangle` derives from `Polygon` then a rectangle *is a* polygon.  Not every polygon, however, is a rectangle.  So `Polygon` can't define the properties of `Rectangle` because other polygons wouldn't know what to do with those properties.

Often, a sensible way to approach this is to start building your derived objects and then refactor into common base objects where appropriate, rather than trying to define your universal catch-all base class and then seeing what sort of derived classes you can make fit.  There are a number of [refactoring patterns](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3GKSsHsE_qLVoAoWooC0yk59RLwV4rfW) to help with this, which address ways to identify and extract common functionality from multiple classes into common base classes.